# $\overline{\theta}$ the maximum likelihood estimator of $\theta \implies$?

Tags: probability, statistics

I can't understand how the following statement holds without any extra conditions on the function $g$:

$\overline{\lambda}$ the maximum likelihood estimator of parameter $\lambda \implies g(\overline{\lambda})$ the maximum likelihood estimator of $g(\lambda)$

Intuitively it would seem that we would need $g$ to be monotionic for this to be true. How can it be shown that this statement holds for an arbitrary function $g$?

Comment: Aaand... what would be your thoughts on the subject?

Comment: @Did Well my thoughts are like I say, I thought $g$ would need to be monotonic for this to be true. I don't know how to go about showing the implication, I haven't really worked with MLEs much yet.

Answer (score 2):

It is true for any function $g$, as can be seen in many introductory book on mathematical statistics. This is called the **invariance property of the MLE** (or sometimes Zehna's theorem).

The idea of the proof is that the transformation $g$ induces a likelihood on its target, and the maximizer of this induced likelihood is the maximum likelihood estimator.

Giving some more details: suppose $g:\Lambda\to\Theta$ is a transformation of your parameter space. For $\theta\in \Theta$, one can define 
$$\Lambda_\theta = \{\lambda \in\Lambda: g(\lambda)=\theta\}.$$
The *induced likelihood* I'm referring to above is given by
$$M(\theta) = \sup_{\lambda\in\Lambda_\theta}L(\lambda),$$
where $L$ is the likelihood function on the original parameter space.

Comment: Many call it "invariance" but it's really _equivariance_.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose the likelihood function is $\alpha\mapsto L(\alpha)$.

Let $\beta=g(\alpha)$. I will assume $g$ is one-to-one.

The likelihood as a function of $\beta$ is not the same function as the likelihood as a function of $\alpha$.

The value of $\alpha$ determines the probability distribution of the data, so that $L(\alpha_0) = \Pr(X=x\mid\alpha=\alpha_0)$, where $x$ is the data actually observed (or if $X$ is a continuous variable, then $L(\alpha_0)=f(x\mid\alpha=\alpha_0)$, where $f$ is the probability density function).

I will give to the likelihood as a function of $\beta$ the name $K$.  Thus
$$K(\beta_0) = \Pr(X=x\mid \beta=\beta_0) = \Pr(X=x\mid g(\alpha)=\beta_0).$$

If $L(\alpha_1)<L(\alpha_2)$ then $\Pr(X=x\mid\alpha=\alpha_1)<\Pr(X=x\mid\alpha=\alpha_2)$, so $\Pr(X=x\mid g(\alpha)=g(\alpha_1))<\Pr(X=x\mid g(\alpha)=g(\alpha_2))$, and so $K(g(\alpha_1))<K(g(\alpha_2))$.

Hence if $\alpha_2$ is a value for which $L(\alpha_1)<L(\alpha_2)$ for EVERY value of $\alpha_1$, then $g(\alpha_2)$ is a value for which $K(g(\alpha_1))<K(g(\alpha_2))$ for EVERY value of $g(\alpha_1)$.